# Why object has to be nulled for IE after it was document.getElementById-ed?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, memory-leaks, null

I often see in third party JavaScript code that after:

```
var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
```

object is often nulled and comment along this operation says that it is done for IE:

```
el = null; // IE
```

What's the real purpose? Any resource on that?

Comment: IIRC, it's because IE otherwise keeps references to _all_ accessible variables in closure scopes, which makes it leak unused non-null references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By nixing a reference they break the corresponding cyclic dependency between the DOM object and JavaScript objects, which are controlled by different sub-systems in older IE (thus being impossible to be garbage-collected).

For example:

```
var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
el.onclick = function () { // here the cyclic reference is created
    /...
};
```

The JavaScript subsystem has now a reference to the `el` element, and the DOM subsystem (the `el` element) has a reference to the JavaScript object (the function plus what it closes in).

You don't have to worry, though, if you add the listeners via `addEventListener`.

To read more about common memory leak pitfalls, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/.